# Problem with ntheorem and minipage

Tags: ntheorem

I have a problem with ntheorem and minipage. If I use a minipage **immediately after** `\begin{mytheorem}`, the name of the theorem is inside the minipage and not placed where I would expect it to be. I have the same problem if I use `\begin{center}` instead of `\begin{minipage}`.
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[framed]{ntheorem}

{\theoremstyle{nonumberbreak}\newtheorem{demo}{Démonstration}}

\begin{document}      
  \begin{demo}
    \begin{minipage}{5cm}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sagittis risus in nisi euismod rutrum. Phasellus a convallis tortor, in tristique sem. Donec ut tempus ligula. Cras eu bibendum diam, a tristique elit. Praesent lobortis gravida ex, ut luctus odio pulvinar eget. Fusce eu nunc sit amet tellus bibendum dictum cursus sit amet elit. Praesent bibendum lectus dolor, a finibus dui placerat et. Curabitur tincidunt, orci sit amet blandit euismod, velit orci maximus sapien, ac fermentum turpis ex ac lacus.
    \end{minipage}
  \end{demo}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the name "Démonstration" is not in the right place

Comment: Insert `\leavevmode\par` just after `begin{demo}`.

Comment: Or, change `\begin{minipage}{5cm}` to `\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}`.

Comment: @Bernard - I'd also recommend `\noindent` after `\par`. :-)

Comment: @Mico:  Oh! yes. I forgot to check this point when I tested. I must say I was quite puzzled by the minipage.

Comment: @Didier - Just out of idle curiosity: Could you provide a use case for a `minipage` environment in the present context?

Comment: I couldn’t test your suggestions yet, because I am not home. I use a mini page because I have text on the left minipage and a figure (drawn with metapost) on the right minipage.

Comment: @Didier: Instead of using minipages, I suggest you try to use the `\InsertBoxR`  command (from the plain TeX macros package `insbox`). If it works in this context, the number of shortened lines is calculated by TeX.

Comment: @Bernard: Thank you for `\InsertBoxR`. I don't know this command, so I will study that.  I would prefer `multicols{2}` but I can't choose the width of both colums. For `\leavevmode\par`, it works but it inserts a blank line

Comment: @Didier From the conversion you had with sir `Bernard`, hope you may require like `wrapfigure`, if yes, please try with the package `\usepackage{wrapfig}`

Comment: @MadyYuvi Thank you. I will look at that